# Can't figure out how to 'map' my data from response| Next.js 13, typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

It's only been a few days since I started learning `next.js`. As for now, I can't figure out how to `fetch` data from `api`. In plain `react`, I used `useState` and `useEffect` to control and `fetch` data. But what about `next.js 13.4`?

```
import { ProductType } from '../Types/productTypes';
import Image from 'next/image';

async function getData() {
    const res = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products');
    if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
    }

    return res.json();
}

export default async function ProductPage() {
    const data: ProductType[] = await getData()

    return (
        <main>
            {data.map((product) => (
                <div key={product.id} className='border p-4'>
                    <h3 className='text-xl font-semibold'>{product.title}</h3>
                    <p className='text-gray-500'>${product.price}</p>
                    <Image src={product.thumbnail} alt={product.title} className='mt-4 mb-2 w-full h-48 object-contain' />
                    <button className='bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 text-white py-2 px-4 rounded'>More details</button>
                </div>
            ))}
        </main>
    );
}
```

My type is next:

```
export type ProductType = {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    price: number;
    discountPercentage: number;
    rating: number;
    stock: number;
    brand: string;
    category: string;
    thumbnail: string;
    images: string[];
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the structure of your response you'll see that its type is like this:

```
type DummyJsonResponse = {
  products: Product[]
  total: number
  skip: number
  limit: number
}
```

You can add this as a return type of your `getData` function:

```
async function getData(): Response<DummyJsonResponse> { ... }
```

And then map over `data.products` instead of `data` (which is not an array).

Comment: There is a mistake that:
"Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: data.map is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

In `nextjs 13` by default every component is a server component which mean server component renders on server.

if you need to use `useState` `useEffect` `useRef` etc, you should mark `use client` top in the component.

You should call your function this way...

```
async function getData() {
    const res = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products');
    if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
    }

    const data:ProductType = await res.json();
    return data;
}
```

**Update Your Type**

You need to update your type with this ...

```
export type ProductType = {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    price: number;
    discountPercentage: number;
    rating: number;
    stock: number;
    brand: string;
    category: string;
    thumbnail: string;
    images: string[];
}[];
```

Just add square bracket in the last.

**In React Component**

```
export default async function ProductPage() {
const response = await getData();

return (
<> {/* Return your code */} </>
 )
}
```

Comment: It's kinda strange but it won't help me


`
async function getData() {
    const res = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products');
    if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
    }
    const data:ProductType = await res.json();
    return data;
}
export default async function ProductPage() {
    const response = await getData()
    return (
        <main>
            {response.map((product) => (
                <div key={product.id} className='border p-4'>
                </div>
            ))}
        </main>
    );
}
`